# How to find files that don't belong to a given user

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, find, recursive

How do I  recursively search for all files or directories that **do not** belong to given user?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the user was `john`:

```
 $ find . ! -user john
```

From `man find`:

```
Operators
! expr True if expr is false.
```